# Export Data of Sql Compact database (mdf File) to Access or Excel or CSV format

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, vb.net

Hi i Have Used Database file for storing Data in my Application.
Now I want to take backup of data in Access, Excel or in Any other
Format. Thank You..

Comment: MS Access or Ms Excel Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Server CE files are with extension sdf.
Check this link http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/ that will allow you to export schema and data of SqlServerCE. Once you export the data, run the output in access (after you create the database). This should make the Access database have the same data as your SqlServerCE database.